# Accessing inbuilt feature by Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera, android-camera

This is something that I am completely unaware of, I do not even know can we do it or its highly impossible! I want to access inbuilt feature of Camera. **For eg:** Take out your Phone(Samsung/Apple/ any phone supports face detect INBUILT) and open Camera(selfie mode), once you come in front of camera it will draw circle around your face, Great! Camera detected your Face without any Code.

Now I am working on `Xamarin.Forms` app in which I am taking picture and doing some operations on it. In my scenario, user flow 
**Open App -> Capture Photo -> View -> & Process at end** 
I want camera to capture photo automatically, once user' face is detected. Can anyone suggest me any pathway or workaround or any other example for my task?

Thank You

Comment: On iOS you are run the camera output through a CoreImage `CIDetector`/ `CIFaceFeature` to determine if there a face in the image and save the frame/photo. On Android there is a `Camera.Face`/`Camera.FaceDetectionListener ` on the `Camara` api and under the "newer" `Camera2` api there is `CaptureResult.StatisticsFaces` and `CaptureResult.StatisticsFaceDetectMode` that can be applied to the camera preview to determine when to take a photo.

Comment: Do you have any example ?

Comment: The "examples" (i.e. apps) that I have would be far to big for an SO answer, but if you have problems with your code implementation of those APIs, post a new question.

Comment: All right. I will try to go ahead with that documentation.. Thanks though..